# Easiest way to map content (in json) to the view (template)?

Tags: templates, json

Basically: I want to 'automatically' map some JSON's attributes to a template's attributes.

Should I do it programmatically or is there a plugin (I prefer this solution, a plugin would be perfect) for that ?

Details: I have a json file with all the data of my page (the trip's information). Then I would like to import this JSON file and to automatically map it's attributes to the template. (eg: the trip's name (in the json) to a template field. To be more complete, I will need to use GraphQl, get a json data, and inject this json in wordpress in order to fullfill the view. How to do that ? Tks.

Answer (score 1):

So you want some client-side javascript templating system... You could build your own, or use one already made - like [this one](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates).

In the context of WordPress, you probably want to create a [custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/) for pages of that type.

Hope that helps!